# Access variable outside a function within a function

Tags: python, function

Sorry if this too naive..

```
global name
name=""

def namecheck(lastname):
    if name:
        name=lastname+name
    else:
        name=lastname

    print name

namecheck("ravi")
```

In a code like this how do access and modifythe variable `name` inside the function without having to pass it as an argument.

Right now I have this error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment`

Comment: The `global` statement should have been used inside the function not in the module.

Comment: Arghh!  Thanks a lot..  That worked !!